# Adding overhead lighting and getting rid of half switched outlets

Tags: wiring

Our ranch house was built in 77 and perhaps it is a sign of those times but none of the bed rooms (or the family and front rooms) have overhead lights. Instead all the bedrooms (and the front room) have half switched outlets. We would like to do do two things: 1. convert the outlets to non-switched and 2. Add overhead lighting and/or ceiling fans. We would like to use the same switches that now connect to the outlets to control the new lights. We would also like to add another switch controlling a chandelier on the opposite side of our front room (which we now use as a dining room). Are we crazy to attempt this ourselves? (I will add that we are avid DYI-ers).

Comment: This question can't really be answered, without knowing more about you, your skill level, and the house. I don't believe this type of question is a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Changing wiring to the extent that you are talking about is a doable project but if you know nothing about wiring or are any bit concerned about feeling safe working with AC mains power it may be best to call in a professional electrician.

Some notes.

Adding ceiling lights to rooms that do not have them is easiest and most feasible if there is attic access above the rooms. Access to the attic allows one to get up there to place decent blocking between ceiling joists to which the electrical box can be secured. This is especially important when you want to support the weight of a ceiling fan from the electrical box. It is also possible to route the wires over to the top of the wall section where the switch is located and drill a hole down into the below stud cavity to poke the light wire down to the switch.

Adding switched lights to the ceiling of a first floor room that has joists above and then living space above that is a more invasive job. This generally requires opening up multiple holes in the drywall or plaster walls. Obviously the wall materials can be restored but it adds lots of work and the need to repaint the room afterwards. Access holes in ceilings that are textured adds an additional challenge in the restoration process. I have done this type of project many times and can say it is doable but be prepared for many hours of work.

Your '70s style house may not have vaulted ceilings but if you so in your dining / front room it may be a challenge to gain overhead access. Vaulted ceilings are very often built up as part of a roof truss construction and it is very likely that there is a possibility of no "attic" type access from above. So for this type of room you are looking at the much more invasive type construction work. If adding the switch for the chandelier is intended to allow controlling the light from two locations it will be necessary to run new wires all way between the existing switch location and the new switch.

Changing the half switched outlets to non-switched outlets is most easily done at the switch location by removing the two wires off the switch and then joining those two wires with a wire nut and pushing it to the back of the switch electrical box.

Another consideration is the size of the boxes where the re-dutied switches are located. There are code requirements on just how many wires can be in a given sized box and adding a wire from a new ceiling light fixture could exceed the box capacity.